# list of list in listcomprehension

Tags: python

I'm a pretty sure that this is a silly question, but I can't wrap my head around what is wrong.

I have a list of lists and I'd like to use list comprehension to create a single list holding all elements (like a flattened list).

What I have tried so far:

```
lol = [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]]
fl = [el for el in al for al in lol]
```

But then I get `NameError: name 'al' is not defined`.

Is this just not doable in list-comprehension or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The ordering of the `for` loops follows that of regular `for` loops. Start from the outside and work inwards

Answer (score 3):

**You Fix**:

```
print([el for al in lol for el in al])
```

Using `list comprehension` (for better understanding):

```
lol = [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11]]
print([item for sublist in lol for item in sublist])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

**EDIT** (for readability):

```
flattened = []
for sublist in lol:
    for item in sublist:
        flattened.append(item)

print(flattened)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

**Using reduce**:

```
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lol))
```

**EDIT 2**:

While I was at it, here is another cooler way using [`deepflatten`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/deepflatten.html):

```
from iteration_utilities import deepflatten       
print(list(deepflatten(lol, depth=1)))
```

**EDIT 3**:

Using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
print (np.concatenate(lol))
```

> You could just `concatenate()` the lists but with a warning that it
>   wont work with single dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right! However the `for`-clauses need inversion:

```
fl = [el for al in lol for el in al]
```